# Passing `table' option to bespoke class, not recognised by `xcolor`

Tags: color, package-options, class-options

I'm working on a document that uses a university-specific class file. For the purposes of this question, I've reduced the class file to one called `test.cls`, which contains the following:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}[2022/01/26]

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\endinput
```

For my TeX file, I want to use the `sgamex` package ([which you can find here](https://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/latex/)). The important feature of this package is that it loads the `xcolor` package with the option `table`.

Of course, `xcolor` has already been loaded by the class file, but that's ok because it's possible to pass options to the class file, which then get offered to any packages loaded. Thus, I expected the following .tex file to pass the `table` option to `test.cls`:

```
\documentclass[table]{test}
\usepackage{sgamex}

\begin{document}

Hello world.

\end{document}
```

However, this gives the error that there is an option clash for `xcolor`. Interestingly, I'm not getting anything warning me about unused options. Can anyone explain why this doesn't work?

Of course, if I change the class file to load `xcolor` with the `table` option, then everything works as expected. However, I cannot change the class file in real life.

Comment: Use `\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}` before \documentclass.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I wonder why the table option doesn't pass properly to xcolor in my version?